# Print to stdout without `printf`, `puts`, `putchar`, etc

Tags: c

Please, how can I make my `main()` function print out the inputs, by calling a function named `_putchar()`?

We are not allowed to use built-in functions like `printf()`, `puts()`, `putchar()`, etc.

The instructions are as follows:

> - You are not allowed to use the standard library. Any use of functions like printf, puts, etc… is forbidden
> - You are allowed to use _putchar

Apparently, we are only allowed to create our own function, which can then be called to our main output.

Here is my code below:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int _putchar(char c)
{
    return 0;
}
```

```c
int main()
{
    _putchar('_');
    _putchar('p');
    _putchar('u');
    _putchar('t');
    _putchar('c');
    _putchar('c');
    _putchar('h');
    _putchar('a');
    _putchar('r');
    _putchar('\n');
    return(0);
}
```

Expected output is:

> _putchar

Comment: You need to add a parameter to `_putchar()`, and then the function should print it.

Comment: Don't tag with a bunch of other random tags like Python.

Comment: "We are not allowed to use inbuilt functions like printf, puts, putchar, etc" This makes no sense. There's no standard way to produce output without using functions like these.

Comment: This exercise presumably came after a lesson, and it was intended to test whether you learned what they taught? Do you have any idea how they expect you to solve it? What was the subject matter of the lesson?

Comment: Are you allowed to use `write()` to the stdout file handle?

Comment: That's my guess, that this was in the context of a lesson on standard out/in/err, and how they're just files that you can `open()` and `write()`. But guessing is stupid, OP just needs to provide more detail if they would like people to be able to help

Comment: [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: The program is meant to print out what is in the main function, with exit code 0

Comment: @edozievictor that is not helpful. Did you read the other comments?

Comment: @jarmod we are not allowed to use standard library functions

Comment: @RemyLebeau the output of the main function, should be the parameter passed from the _putchar function.

Comment: At some point you'll need to invoke a syscall, and you cannot use anything from the standard library (which includes `putchar`)? Do they expect you to do inline assembly?

Comment: @edozievictor you are just restating what your question already says. We know what you WANT to accomplish, but the question is HOW are you allowed to do that, given your VERY limited restrictions? Clearly your instructor is EXPECTING you to *implement* `_putchar()` to write output, but you eliminated all of the normal ways to actually accomplish that goal

Comment: `_putchar` is not a standard C, it's most likely your course's extension. The function you've provided does nothing and it's impossible to use it to print to the output. Something is missing.

Comment: I think you guys are right. The test is meant to make the program return 0

Comment: @RemyLebeau The task is for the program to return exit code 0, I think the program did

Comment: @edozievictor that is not what you asked for

Answer (score 2):

You might be expected to implement `_putchar` using a system call such as `write` on POSIX systems or something similar on other platforms:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int _putchar(char c)
{
    return write(1, &c, 1) == 1 ? c : -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int _putchar(char c)
{
    int n = 0;
    n = write(1,&c,1);
    return n;
}

int main()
{
    int m = 0;
    m = _putchar('_');
    m = _putchar('p');
    m = _putchar('u');
    m = _putchar('t');
    m = _putchar('c');
    m = _putchar('c');
    m = _putchar('h');
    m = _putchar('a');
    m = _putchar('r');
    m = _putchar('\n');
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: `char *buf` should be `const char *buf`.

Comment: I changed. Thank you.

Comment: Based on the OP's stated requirement, clearly `_putchar()` is expected to take an input value, which is then written to output, but this code does not do that. Your solution should look more like this instead: `int _putchar(char c) { write(1,&c,1); return ...; } int main() { _putchar('_'); _putchar('p'); ... return 0; }`

Comment: @Whozcry why do you keep making your `_putchar()` be different than what the OP showed in the question? `int _putchar(char c)`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sorry, English is not my native language. What does 'op' mean? Do you mean write code like int _putchar(char c) that return int value and argument  is of type char?

Comment: @Whozcry "*What does 'op' mean?*" - it means "original poster" ie the person asking the question. "*Do you mean ...*" - I mean, you should start with the code the OP presented and just make it work. But you keep changing `__putchar()` to do different things than what the OP asked for. They need to pass in a single `char` by value and output it. Not take in a pointer to a null-terminated string, or a pointer to a char.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I updated my answer, Now I think it's right.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you. You see how about my answer about other question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76526432/explanation-needed-for-this-assembler-code/76527915#76527915