# Recursion to print out every array that the sum of its components is equal to a given number

Tags: c, recursion

So we are given an array `v[]={2,6} and d=10` we have to print out every sub array so that the sum is equal to d

for example with the give d and v[] we should print out these arrays

```
2 2 2 2 2
6 2 2
2 6 2 
2 2 6
```

This is my current program but i cant seem to print anything.

I assume that the problem is when im back tracking but i dont have any current ideas

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void findSolutions(int v[], int n, int d, int current[], int index) {

    if(index>n)
    {
        current=realloc(current,index*sizeof (int));
    }
    if (d == 0) {
        
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            printf("%d ", current[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        return;
    }
    if (d < 0 || index >= n) {
        return;
    }


    current[index] = v[index];
    findSolutions(v, n, d - v[index], current, index + 1);

    findSolutions(v, n, d, current, index + 1);
}

int main() {
    int v[] = {2, 6};
    int n = 2;
    int d = 10;
    int *current= malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    findSolutions(v, n, d, current, 0);
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you haven't done it before, now is very good time to learn how to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your programs. For example to use a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to catch possible crashes, or step through the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: A possible couple of hints though: If you have an array of `index` elements, what is the valid range of indexes for that array? Is `index` itself included in that range? And if `index >= n`, is `index` valid for indexing the array `v`? Also take care to check that `realloc` doesn't fail.

Comment: Looks like `n` will always be `2`... Does this provide a clue as to where to look?

Comment: @Fe2O3 But when i increase index doesnt it go to the next value?

Comment: `if (d < 0 || index >= n) { return; }` ... No... `:-)`

Comment: @Fe2O3 Fine ig ill have to think a bit more on this

Comment: Is _recursion_ a requirement of the solution? Seems this could be solved with _iteration_ ('though I haven't actually done that...)

Comment: @Fe2O3 It is a requirement

Comment: `2 2 2 2 2` is not a sub-array of `{2, 6}`.

Comment: `current=realloc(current,index*sizeof (int))` After this (if `realloc` is successful) `current` is an array with indexes from `0` to `index - 1` (inclusive). Yet you use `current[index]` later in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code use `malloc()`, but no use `free()` to free memory that will result in memory leak.

I don't know why you use twice `findSolutions(v, n, d - v[index], current, index + 1);` and `findSolutions(v, n, d, current, index + 1);` in `findSolutions()`

So I rewrite it, here is my answer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void findSolutions(int *a , int* current , int num , int minusResult , int len, int sum)
{
    if(sum > minusResult)
        return;
    else if(sum == minusResult){
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
            printf("%d ", current[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        //printf("len is %d\n",len);
        return;
    }else{
        for(int j = 0; j < num; j++){
            sum = sum + a[j];
            current[len] = a[j];
            findSolutions(a, current, num, minusResult, len+1, sum);
            sum = sum - a[j];
        }
    }
}


int main() {
    int v[] = {2, 6};
    int n = 2;
    int d = 10;
    int sum = 0;
    int minusResult = 0;
    int *current= malloc(1000*sizeof(int));
    if(NULL == current){
        printf("malloc current failed\n");
        return -1;
    }
    memset(current, 0, 1000*sizeof(int));
    findSolutions(v, current, n, d, minusResult, sum);
    free(current);    
    current = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

Run it will output:

```
2 2 2 2 2 
2 2 6 
2 6 2 
6 2 2
```

And if you think `2 2 6` and `2 6 2` and `6 2 2` are the same result, then want to output `2 2 6` at once, you can use below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void findSolutions(int *a , int* current , int num , int minusResult , int len, int sum , int loc)
{
    if(sum > minusResult)
        return;
    else if(sum == minusResult){
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
            printf("%d ", current[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        return;
    }else{
        for(int j = loc; j < num; j++){
            sum = sum + a[j];
            current[len] = a[j];
            findSolutions(a, current, num, minusResult, len+1, sum, loc);
            sum = sum - a[j];
            loc++;
        }
    }
}


int main() {
    int v[] = {2, 6};
    int n = 2;
    int d = 10;
    int sum = 0;
    int loc = 0;
    int minusResult = 0;
    int *current= malloc(1000*sizeof(int));
    if(NULL == current){
    printf("malloc current failed\n");
    return -1;
    }
    memset(current, 0, 1000*sizeof(int));
    findSolutions(v, current, n, d, minusResult, sum, loc);
    free(current);    
    current = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

Run it will output:

```
2 2 2 2 2 
2 2 6
```

Comment: @SeverjanLici I'm glad that I can help you. My mother tongue is not English. But I think may be  `Apprechiate` should be `Appreciate`.

Comment: UV because the first (tricky) code block seems to work. Would like to DV because SO is supposed to **help** OP's with their code, not simply **dump** a working version for them to copy/paste into their homework assignments... Where's the analysis of the OP's mistake(s)? PS: `1000` is excessive and `malloc()` is not necessary... What's the minimum size needed for `current[]`?

Comment: @Fe2O3  Sorry, my mother tongue is not English, what is UV and DV? I am Chinese that I never heard before. And so I don't know that "them to copy/paste into their homework assignments".  As `Where's the analysis of the OP's mistake(s)?`, problem of his code is a bit more, such as why he use two `findSolutions(v, n, d - v[index], current, index + 1);` and  `findSolutions(v, n, d, current, index + 1);` that let me not understand, so I rewrite it. I come stackoverflow mainly for study English, Because my English is poor, second if someone have c problem that I can solve it, I will give answer.

Comment: @Fe2O3 You are right that `malloc()`  is not necessary at here, In China, pursue a `standard` answer, but then I learned that there is `no standard` answer to the questions in western developed countries. It is to stimulate the imagination of students. That's why people in western developed countries are more creative than Chinese. The answer to the original question is not only my method. I use `malloc()` for `exhibit`  how  to correctly use `malloc()`  and `free()` . About this point, I write it at begin of my answer.

Comment: SO (Stack Overflow) uses abbreviations: UV (upvote = +10pts) and DV (downvote = -2pts)... "_that let me not understand, so I rewrite it._" and "_c problem that I can solve it, I will give answer_" Will you sit beside the OP (Original Post(er)) in an exam or a job interview?? The OP may not understand your answer and learn nothing... This question is obviously a homework assignment. Providing the answer (for free) is NOT helpful to anyone. Without understanding OP's problem understanding the assignment, who is helped by giving away a working solution? NOT the OP!!

Comment: "_how to correctly use malloc() and free()_" Actually, `int *p = malloc(1000*sizeof *p);` is better (than `1000*sizeof(int*)`)... Why? Think about this... Using `malloc()` is inappropriate in this question, so it should not be there. Using `memset()` is worse. Why not `calloc()`? Why `1000`? Again: What is the min/max size needed for `current[]`?

Comment: Why `#include <string.h>`? Without `malloc()`, why `#include <stdlib.h>`? Extraneous code that isn't required... Why use `else` after a block ending with `return;`? Extra code that suggests complexity that is not there. Why **2**definitions of `j` in the final `else` block of your function? In `main()`, the call `findSolutions(v, current, n, d, minusResult, sum, loc);` could be `findSolutions( v, current, n, d, 0, 0, 0 );` and 3 variables could be removed. Why `current = NULL;` as the last statement before termination?

Comment: @Fe2O3 Before someone told me that OP is abbreviate by original problem, thank you for you told me that what is DV and UV, usually I will give answer with explation, but I don't know why he use two `findSolutions(v, n, d - v[index], current, index + 1);` and `findSolutions(v, n, d, current, index + 1);`,  It may be due to the difference between education in western countries and China, even if you tell me that the original question is homework, I still don't know where to tell that the original question is homework.

Comment: You've got me looking at your code again... What is with the misalignment of the parameter `minusResult` between the call from `main()` and the function itself? Too many variables lead to confusion...

Comment: @Fe2O3 I know that you said `calloc()` is better than `malloc()`, because `calloc()` is use less memory than `malloc()`, `1000` is enough big that I tested ok, so I use 1000. As `What is the min/max size needed for current[]`, the value of max of current[] is `max of len in my code`, the value of minix of current[] is `0(no answer)` or `1(only one answer)`.

Comment: @Fe2O3 `Why #include <string.h>`, because `memset()` need to use #include <string.h>. `Why use else after a block ending with return;` because `findSolutions` is recursively call, condition is not meet, then function need to return(function call occur at `stack`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76526432/explanation-needed-for-this-assembler-code/76527915#76527915). About `3 variables could be removed`, you are right, but I want to clear for parameter meaning. About `Why current = NULL;`, it is to prevent then adding code errors using `current`, add Why current = NULL is personal habit

Comment: "_1000 is enough big that I tested ok, so I use 1000._" So you don't _understand_ the problem... The minimum is the # of items in the array. The maximum needed is the target value / smallest array value (+1 to probe exceeding the target.) Think! Here the target is `10`. If the smallest array value were `1`, the code would need, at most, 11 elements in the array you call `current[]`... (Here, the smallest is `2` so `current[10/2+1]` is all that's needed.) Guessing `1000` is simply _guessing_, not programming... AND, what's the purpose of `loc` in your solution???

Comment: @Fe2O3 About `what's the purpose of loc in your solution???`, as I said in answer `And if you think 2 2 6 and 2 6 2 and 6 2 2 are the same result, then want to output 2 2 6 at once, you can use below code:`, The use of `loc` is not need for the origin problem , it just occur other situation that when I write code. So I reserve it.

Comment: @Fe2O3 Sure, I think I can use `calloc()` to rewrite it may be result in use less variable.

Comment: "_The use of loc is not the origin problem_" Then why does your first example (that is the OP's objective) contain `loc` but never use it? As incomprehensible as the OP's double use of calling the recursion... Why does your second example set `j = loc` twice?

Comment: @Fe2O3 About `The use of loc is not the origin problem` as I said that my English is poor, but I have changed it. Pleaea see again that comment . I think I can say that I forget delete it, as you know, `my code sometimes has mistakes, it's not that perfect`, but I have the courage to write it out, through other people's `criticism`, I can find my problems for correct it. And at here althought `loc` is not use in piece of code, it doesn't like incomprehesible as the OP's double use of calling the recursion, because `loc` is not use.

Comment: @Fe2O3 As `Why does your second example set j = loc twice?`, I forget delete the first line of `j = loc`. I will changed my answer. Thank you for you point that.

Comment: Last comment from me: `malloc/calloc`... Notice `current[len] = a[j];`... All used elements of `current[]` are assigned a value (before any might be printed.) If you had confidence in your algorithm, you would see that `malloc()` without `memset()` would be sufficient. Thus, no need for `#include <string.h>`. Quality counts when writing an answer... Good luck...

Comment: @Fe2O3 For your last comment, I say that "Yes, you are right", but `malloc()` after then check if `address` return by `malloc()`  is `NULL`, then set value of `adress` to all 0 `is just my habit` for identify potential problems. Thank you for your opinion.

Comment: @Fe2O3 You said "Quality counts when writing an answer", yes, you are right, I can do it, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77070194/libpcap-doesnt-do-anything-windows

Comment: Well done! If you answer questions on topics that you know, your answers may be praised. Don't expect to earn points or praise for "this answer seems to work... sometimes."

Comment: @Fe2O3 Ok, I know, I will do my utmost to provide high-quality answers. I will add more explain for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

There appear to be several problems in you code addressed by comments below. Consistent formatting would make your life easier.

```
    if(index>n) // We'll see this never is true...
    {
        current=realloc(current, index*sizeof (int)); // so this never happens.
        /* Never happening is actually good.
         * realloc() may return a new address of heap memory
         * You don't pass 'current' back up to higher levels, so their stale copy of
         * the pointer 'current' could point to de-allocated memory. (UB awaits!)
         */
    }
    if (d == 0) { // 'd' is not a descriptive variable name
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) // remove unnecessary braces
            printf("%d ", current[i]);

        printf("\n");
        return;
    }

    if (d < 0 || index >= n) // Once index = 2, game over. Data requires at least 3
        return;

    current[index] = v[index]; // probably want "index - 1" for base 0 indexing

    findSolutions(v, n, d - v[index], current, index + 1); // close!!!

    findSolutions(v, n, d, current, index + 1); // Looks like vestigial attempt
}

int main() {
    int v[] = {2, 6}; // Not the best variable names!
    int n = 2;
    int d = 10;
    int *current= malloc(n*sizeof(int)); // could be NULL and let realloc() do the work

    findSolutions(v, n, d, current, 0);
    
    return 0;
}
```

---

It's apparent that this code is *shrinking* the target value (from `10`), toward zero (or lower), the *base case*. Clever, as this means one less parameter needed!

Below is an annotated version. I hope this helps clarify a few things.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Helper function to find minimum value in array */
int arrMinVal( const unsigned arr[], const size_t a_sz ) {
    size_t minInd = 0;
    for( size_t i = 1; i < a_sz; i++ )
        if( arr[ minInd ] > arr[ i ] )
            minInd = i;
    return arr[ minInd ];
}

/* The recursive function.
 * Notice the sequence of parameters:
 * - remaining balance of target
 * - source array and its size
 * - array of values (incl. duplicates) used so far (and its size)
 */
int solve_ex( const int remain, const unsigned arr[], const size_t a_sz, int soln[], int len ) {
    if( remain < 0 ) // Overshoot! No good, so return...
        return 0;

    if( !remain ) { // Bull's eye! Print (in reverse) the working combination found
        while( len-- )
            printf( "%d ", soln[ len ] );
        putchar( '\n' );
        return 1; // return 1 to increase tally of found combinations
    }

    // Recurse trying out each value of the source array one at a time
    int cnt = 0;
    for( size_t i = 0; i < a_sz; i++ ) {
        soln[ len ] = arr[ i ]; // Remember this value (for printing)
        // Tally the wanted combinations found at "lower levels"
        // First parameter 'shrinks' the target toward zero (as you had)
        // Last parameter indicates one more value has been added to "soln[]"
        cnt += solve_ex( remain - arr[ i ], arr, a_sz, soln, len + 1 );
    }
    // exhausted possibilities at this level, so return tally
    return cnt;
}

/* 'Bridging' function so that main() is less cluttered */
int solve( const int target, const unsigned arr[], const size_t a_sz ) {
    // determine max required size of solution array
    // For example: with { 2, 6 }, finding 10 requires at most 5 entries (5*2=10)
    // Add 1 to allow for "overshoot"...
    int n = target / arrMinVal( arr, a_sz ) + 1;
    int *soln = malloc( n * sizeof *soln ); // Could be VLA, instead.
    /* for brevity, malloc presumed to work */

    int cnt = solve_ex( target, arr, a_sz, soln, 0 ); // get into it...

    free( soln ); // clean up

    return cnt; // return
}

int main( void ) { // Uncluttered...
    const unsigned arr[] = { 2, 6 };
    const int target = 10;

    // Eventually, code to get user input may be added.
    // Sometimes, no solutions can be found. Give the user feedback.
    printf( "%d solutions found\n", solve( target, arr, sizeof arr/sizeof arr[0] ) );

    return 0;
}
```

I hope this helps...

Comment: thanks for the reply and i aprechiate the time you took to write the very detailed code for me. I apologize for not thanking you earlier but i had an exam today and i was without sleep the whole night

Comment: You're welcome. After you catch up on sleep, copy this code and strip out the explanatory comments (after understanding them). You'll see it is not quite as massive as it appears. Writing smaller _helper_ functions is a way to keep the logic clear. For instance, simple get the (+'ve int) target value and another function to have user input array values. (Note: only counting numbers accepted!) Each function does only one thing. Easy to test. (Printing 'found' arrays could be factored out of this code, too!) Cheers! No go to sleep...