# libpcap doesn't do anything (Windows)

Tags: c, windows, gcc, libpcap, npcap

For 2 days now I am trying to get a simple packet live capture to work with libpcap and npcap on Windows 11. I am using MSYS2-compiled MinGW GCC compiler. I have installed libpcap through pacman and linked it. I have installed npcap with wireless support as well as the loopback driver, LWF, LWF with wireless support, and the WFP callout driver (through NPFInstall.exe). The npcap service is running and wireshark works well on its own. My Wi-Fi network adapter does not support monitor mode, so I couldn't try that with WlanHelper.exe

The code I first tested was:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pcap.h>

static void init_npcap_dll_path ()
{
    BOOL(WINAPI *SetDllDirectory)(LPCTSTR);
    char sysdir_name[512];
    int len;

    SetDllDirectory = (BOOL(WINAPI *)(LPCTSTR)) GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), "SetDllDirectoryA");

    if(SetDllDirectory == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error in SetDllDirectory\n");
    }
    else
    {
        len = GetSystemDirectory(sysdir_name, 480);

        if(!len) printf("Error in GetSystemDirectory (%d)\n", GetLastError());

        strcat(sysdir_name, "\\Npcap");

        if(SetDllDirectory(sysdir_name) == 0)
            printf("Error in SetDllDirectory(\"System32\\Npcap\")\n");
    }
}

int main (void)
{
    /* No error here: */
    init_npcap_dll_path();

    /* Modules were loaded successfully */
    HMODULE lib1 = LoadLibrary("wpcap");
    HMODULE lib2 = LoadLibrary("Packet");

    char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
    char *dev = "\\Device\\NPF_{B4B56B26-D9F1-49CF-831F-DD58B7DA5ACC}";
    //char *dev = "b4b56b26-d9f1-49cf-831f-dd58b7da5acc"; /* Tried this as well */

    pcap_t* handle = pcap_open_live(dev, BUFSIZ, 1, 1000, errbuf);

    if(handle == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open device %s: %s\n", dev, errbuf);
        return 2;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And the pcap error was that "live packet capture is not supported on this system".

Moreover, even a simple network adapter lookup doesn't work:

```
char *dev = pcap_lookupdev(errbuf);

if(dev == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't find default device: %s\n", errbuf);
    return(2);
}
```

The error reads "no suitable device found"

Running the application as admin does nothing. I really don't know what else I could try to get it working, except maybe using VS and linking the .lib files from the npcap SDK implicitly...

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If you are building your program with the MSYS2 libpcap package (as "I have installed libpcap through pacman" implies), then, unless the libpcap in that package was compiled on a system that has Npcap *and* the Npcap SDK installed, *and* the build process for that package told CMake where the Npcap SDK is installed, then the libpcap in that package will *not* support packet capture (and shouldn't be advertised by he MSYS2 package site as being "for packet capture"!).

Note that [there are both "libpcap" and "mingw-w64-libpcap" packages on the MSYS2 packages site](https://packages.msys2.org/search?t=pkg&q=libpcap).  They do not seem to indicate what the difference is between the packages; you might try uninstalling whichever one you installed, install the other one, and see if that works.

You also might want to file an issue on one or both of those packages on [the MSYS2 MINGW-packages issues list](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues) if one or both of them doesn't support packet capture.

I don't know if there's a way to, in MinGW, link with a program with an SDK that provides a Visual Studio .lib file, but, if that's supported, you might want to install the Npcap SDK and build with that, instead.

(Note also that using `LoadLibrary()` to load the wpcap and Packet libraries, without doing anything with the handles you get back from that, does absolutely nothing useful.)

> wireshark works well on its own

That's because Wireshark dynamically loads wpcap with `LoadLibrary()`, gets pointers to all of the libpcap functions that Wireshark uses with `GetProcAddress()`, and has code to call the libpcap functions using those pointers, done in a fashion similar to the way Tom describes in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77070487/16139739).  That means that it directly calls (through pointers) the Npcap versions of the libpcap functions, and Npcap *is* built to support packet capture, so that works.

The code in Wireshark to do this is... complicated, for reasons having to do with Wireshark supporting multiple versions of libpcap, with different capabilities, on both UN*Xes and Windows (both WinPcap and Npcap).  You probably don't need all that complication - just follow Tom's suggestion.

Comment: I will try uninstalling mingw-w64-libpcap and installing libcap! I do have both npcap and the SDK on my PC, though, yas you stated it only provides a MSVS-compatible statics to link against. MSYS/MinGW do not have utilities to deal with this. The odd thing however, is that it is not just the packet capture not working, but also the library's complete inability to detect a device (by virtue of both pcap_findalldevs and pcap_lookupdev)

Comment: And if nothing works, I think I will use the windows port of tcpdump or tshark and will interface it through a shellexecute/pipe in my AHK program.

Comment: ok so this is what I had installed and what I can install:
mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-libpcap 1.10.4-1
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-libpcap 1.10.4-1 [installed]
ucrt64/mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libpcap 1.10.4-1
clang64/mingw-w64-clang-x86_64-libpcap 1.10.4-1
msys/libpcap 1.10.0-1 (libraries)
msys/libpcap-devel 1.10.0-1 (development)

Comment: *loading pcap_findalldevs from wpcap.dll worked!

Comment: Thank you for your affirmation of my answer. I am vote up your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The error is use of `LoadLibrary`, see [LoadLibraryA function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibrarya)

correct use of `LoadLibrary` is:

```
HMODULE hModule = LoadLibrary("xxxxxxx.dll");
if(hModule == NULL)
{
    // error warning
}
```

And if you use `LoadLibrary`, why not use `GetProcAddress`, see [GetProcAddress function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getprocaddress)

Then you need define a poniter of function, like this:

```
typedef int (*pFunc)(int a , int b)
```

Then use `GetProcAddress`

```
pFunc PPPfunc = (pFunc)GetProcAddress(hModule, "NameOfFunction");
int d = PPPfunc(1, 2);
```

Comment: Sorry, but the error has nothing to do with the usage of LoadLibrary or winapi in general. The usage of LoadLibrary is correct:
"If the string specifies a module name without a path and the file name extension is omitted, the function appends the default library extension ".DLL" to the module name. To prevent the function from appending ".DLL" to the module name, include a trailing point character (.) in the module name string."

Comment: @Edenia  Ok, I’m sorry I couldn’t help you.

Comment: @Edenia Can you explain in detail how you operated?